# Project Euler #35 - Circular Primes

Tags: swift, primes

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler's problem #35](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35) which asks:

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>
> There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.
>
> How many circular primes are there below one million?

In order to solve the problem I'm using the following code in Swift:

```
let size = 1000000

func ESieve(x : Int) -> [Bool] {

    var primes = [Bool](count: x + 1, repeatedValue: true)
    primes[0] = false
    primes[1] = false

    for var i = 2; i < primes.count; i++ {
        if !primes[i] {
           continue
        }

        for (var j = 2*i; j < primes.count; j += i) {
           primes[j] = false
        }
    }

    return primes
}

let sieve = ESieve(size)

func getPrimes() -> [Int] {

   var array = [Int]()
   for (var i = 0; i < sieve.count; i++) {
      if sieve[i] {
        array.append(i)
      }
   }
   return array
}

let primes = getPrimes()


func rotations(v : [Int]) -> [Int] {
   var result = [Int]()

   for (var i = 0; i < v.count; i++) {
      var r = 0
      for (var j = i; j < v.count + i; j++) {
         r = 10*r + v[j % v.count]
      }
      result.append(r)
   }
   return result
}

func getArray(x : Int) -> [Int] {
   
   var array = [Int]()
   var i = x
   while i > 0 {
     array.append(i%10)
     i /= 10
   }
   return array
}

func isAllPrime(v : [Int]) -> Bool {
   
   for i in v {
     if !sieve[i] {
       return false
     }
   }
   return true
}

var s = 0
for (var i = 0; i < primes.count; i++) {
   var array = getArray(primes[i])
   var perms = rotations(array)
   if isAllPrime(perms) {
      s++
   }
}

println(s)
```

All the functions seems to work properly. Even when I set `size` to 100, I get the correct result of 13 with the correct circular primes, but I keep getting the wrong result at the end and can't see where the problem is.

Comment: You may also want to consider, rather than using C-style `for` loops, instead using `for...in` loops as well as using `map` and `reduce`.  Doing this makes your code a lot easier to understand and will help with finding bugs (though, maybe not this one).  [Here's](https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/6359fa871847d779aa95) an equivalent program to yours (which has the same problem) using these techniques.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks for your suggestion, as person coming from a C background, I tend to use these kind of loops but I will definitely consider switching to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't want to deprive you of the joy of finding a PE solution, therefore
I'll give only a hint:

Check the output of `rotations(getArray(N))` for numbers `N` with 3
or more digits. It is not what you expect (but can be fixed easily).

Answer (score 2):

I thought that Martin point you with the problem in his answer, nevertheless I think in this kind of problem the efficiency it's very important too.

My advice to improve your code is in your Sieve of Eratosthenes, you can improve it a lot changing the following line :

```
for i in 2..<primes.count
```

For this one:

```
for (var i = 2; i * i <= primes.count; ++i)
```

The above improvement perform only simple sieving not exceeding root `n`.

There are more improvements you can do it, but depends of you, I strongly recommend you the following two articles of a experienced russian coder in programming contest :

- [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/eratosthenes_sieve)
- [Sieve of Eratosthenes with linear time work](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/prime_sieve_linear)

You have to translate it to read it because are in Russian, but you can use the google translator.

I hope this help you.

Comment: There is a dedicated site http://codereview.stackexchange.com for the review of working code, so if OP has fixed the code (s)he might post it there for possible improvements.

Answer (score 0):

A hint.  Consider what happens if your starting prime, before rotating, contains the digit '8'.